# How can I write my own context menu for copy & paste?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing an application with EditText driven widget. and I'd like to create my own copy & paste menu. To replace android default menu on EditText, what should I do?
Just overriding long click? or is there another way to implement?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi did the default copy & paste functions still work after you made your own context menu?

Answer (score 2):

EditText should already have a context menu enabled. If it were not, then you would have to enable it by calling [registerForContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#registerForContextMenu%28android.view.View%29). Once you have the context menu enabled, you have to add items to it. This is done in [onCreateContextMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu%28android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo%29) by using one of the [Menu.add methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int%29).

The hard part is writing the code for [onContextItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29) after the user has selected an option. Saving text to the clipboard is simply a matter of calling `((ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)).setText("myText");`. However, first we need to find what text to copy. I haven't figured this last part out yet, but I am hopeful that I will soon.

**Related Questions**

- [Show context menu when link is long pressed in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662992/show-context-menu-when-link-is-long-pressed-in-textview/2671396#2671396)

Comment: I made a custom text-selection/context toolbar where I added the functionality for the user to be able to make a selected text  bold/italic/underline etc. but after the customization, the default functions copy/paste/cut dont work anymore, but the icons for them still appears? How can theese be activated again? my own custom methods for bold/italic etc. does however work!

Answer (score 1):

It is considered to be somewhat of a standard exercise to implement copy/paste the hard way by overwriting the menu system, creating the menu items yourself, and your own internal buffer.

However, that is not how it should be done if a better way is available on the platform. Reimplementing platform functions is good for learning but bad for maintenance.

Community Wiki as this is not a real answer and I should not get rep for this.

Comment: My personal opinion is same as yours, but always client does..., there is no way without implementing my own copy & paste menu.
Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: A comment is generally better for this kind of thing

Comment: @casebash well since it got accepted answer it obviously wasn't.

Comment: You said its not a real answer yourself. If you don't believe its a real answer and you don't need either to format code or the extra characters, then you should use a comment. If, on the other hand, you think it is a real answer, then you shouldn't say it isn't.