# Show context menu when link is long pressed in TextView

Tags: android, contextmenu, textview

I have a `TextView` with its `MovementMethod` set to `LinkMovementMethod`. Text added to the `TextView` is a combination of normal text and URLs. For URLs, I would like to offer a context menu when the URL is long pressed for doing things such as copying the address. I've had a look at the source for `LinkMovementMethod` but it doesn't seem to have any long pressed related code I could override. Any ideas on how to go around achieving this?

Comment: You may also want to look at this question for [implementing copying in a context menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226836/how-can-i-write-my-own-context-menu-for-copy-paste). It doesn't have an answer atm, but I am working on finding one

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use registerForContextMenu eg:

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    registerForContextMenu(tv);
```

and then override the onCreateContextMenu to create a menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            // Create your context menu here
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");        
}
```

where you can use the ID of the view to pass on to the events that occur on pressing of a menu item, in order to differentiate which view called the event.

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Call your function to preform for buttons pressed in a context menu
    // can use item.getTitle() or similar to find out button pressed
    // item.getItemID() will return the v.getID() that we passed before

}
```

Comment: I'm want to only show a context menu only when the URL is long pressed so I can give some options specific to that link like 'Copy' and 'Share'

Comment: @Al: If you register a context menu, it only appears on a long press