# Android: ViewPager and Context Menus

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using the ViewPager from the Android Support package (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager). My ViewPager layout contents contains TextViews in a LinearLayout on each page.

I would like to be able to use a ContextMenu for each TextView. I have tried the code below where I registerForContextMenu with the ViewPager view, but the onCreateContextMenu method is never called.

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mypager);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
registerForContextMenu(viewPager);
```

Is it possible to use registerForContextMenu in conjunction with the ViewPager type?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your `TextView` for a `ContextMenu` and not `ViewPager`.

[See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671396/420015)

Comment: Thanks for the response aneal. That works as expected. I hoped there might be a more generic way of doing it, similar to ListView, such that the ContextMenuInfo object would be populated for any item that was selected, so it's easier to track which item was selected, but I guess those components aren't really comparable (I'm not sure exactly the best way of tracking which item was selected though if the ContextMenuInfo isn't populated, think I have more reading to do!)