# How can I get to "Select All" text from multiple TextViews?

Tags: android

The TextViews have `android:TextIsSelectable="true"`. However on a long press the user can select text associated with one TextView only. What can I do to have 'Select All' capability? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Android has no default behavior to allow a user to select the text from a list of Textviews.

If you want this functionality, you will need to create a listener that listens for an event of your choosing, like a long press on one of your textviews, and then you will need to get all of the text from your text views and do whatever you want to do with the text.

Once you have all of the text you could store it all in the clipboard (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)

Or you can highlight the text in each textview by doing the following for each textview (Obviously adjust as needed):

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
TV.setText("Italic, highlighted, bold.", TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

Spannable WordtoSpan = (Spannable) TV.getText();

WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFFFF00), 8, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

Also if you want to provide a custom option to your users to do all of this then you can
try the solution given in this question: [Show context menu when link is long pressed in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662992/show-context-menu-when-link-is-long-pressed-in-textview)

Once you do that you can add your own menu and then do something when it is chosen.

Comment: I do require the capability of "Select All" but it must maintain the ability for the user to slide the markers across variable amount of text across continuous TextViews.

Comment: You are going to need to build that functionality in.

Comment: Has any one built this kind of functionality? I too require it.. Please help... :(